# Discord.js check if user is in a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The code is a response after a user clicked on a button with id "pohovor_request". The bot should check if there is any user with a specific role on server (that works) and the second IF should check if the user that clicked on the button is in a specific channel.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
  const { customId, user, guild } = interaction;
  if (customId === 'pohovor_request') {
    const targetRoleID = roles['aktivniSpravcePohovoru'];
    const targetChannelID = channels['cekarna'];
    
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get(targetRoleID);
    if (!role || !guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has(role.id)).size) {
      await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale momentálně na serveru není nikdo s požadovanou rolí.');
      return;
    }
    
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelID);
    if (!channel || !channel.members.has(user.id)) {
      await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale musíte být připojeni ve specifickém hlasovém kanálu pro žádost o pohovor.');
      return;
    }
    
    console.log("Ok");
    
  }
});
```

When i tested the code, the bot always responed Ok, even tho i was ort wasnt in the specific channel.

Answer (score 1):

The `user.id` refers to the ID of the user who clicked the button, not the ID of a GuildMember.

You can use the `guild.members.fetch()` method to fetch the member object for the user, and then check if the member is in the specified channel using the `member.voice.channel` property.

Here's the modified code:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
  const { customId, user, guild } = interaction;
  if (customId === 'pohovor_request') {
    const targetRoleID = roles['aktivniSpravcePohovoru'];
    const targetChannelID = channels['cekarna'];
    
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get(targetRoleID);
    if (!role || !guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has(role.id)).size) {
      await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale momentálně na serveru není nikdo s požadovanou rolí.');
      return;
    }
    
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelID);
    // Fetch the guild member using the user ID.
    const member = await guild.members.fetch(user.id);
    
    if (!channel || member.voice.channelId !== targetChannelID) {
      await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale musíte být připojeni ve specifickém hlasovém kanálu pro žádost o pohovor.');
      return;
    }
    
    console.log("Ok");
  }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The button interaction has a channel and channelId property you can use to check if the channel is the target channel

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    const { customId, user, guild, channelId } = interaction;
    if (customId === 'pohovor_request') {
        const targetRoleID = roles['aktivniSpravcePohovoru'];
        const targetChannelID = channels['cekarna'];

        const role = guild.roles.cache.get(targetRoleID);
        if (!role || !guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has(role.id)).size) {
            await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale momentálně na serveru není nikdo s požadovanou rolí.');
            return;
        }

        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelID);
        if (!channel || channelId !== targetChannelID) {
            await interaction.reply('Je nám líto, ale musíte být připojeni ve specifickém hlasovém kanálu pro žádost o pohovor.');
            return;
        }

        console.log("Ok");
    }
});
```